# JMeter load testing web application

Tags: authentication, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I need to test a web-application using JMeter.

Every time I give the path, it gets redirected to auth0 to login
Is there a way I can save the credentials, so that every path I mention is accessed with those credentials and doesn't always redirect to login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably no. Consider each JMeter thread (virtual user) a normal user using a real browser.

If you [open a new browser window in "porno mode"](https://www.howtogeek.com/269265/how-to-enable-private-browsing-on-any-web-browser/) and try to give an URL which requires authentication - you will be redirected to the login page.

However if you're logged in already - you should be able to open any page without providing credentials.

In the absolute majority of web applications it's being implemented via [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) so given you add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter) to your [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) - you should be able to navigate through your application (given the first N [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers which are responsible for login are successful)